# Find out the cheapest item

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm still new to Java and Eclipse. I'm supposed to find out the cheapest item in a list through a generic class and print out it's parameters. I have this:

```
public class Store<T extends Item>{

public List<T> items = new ArrayList<T>();

 public void addItem(T it){
         items.add(it);
 }

public T cheapestItem(){
        T cheapest;

        Collections.sort(items, (i1, i2) -> i1.getPrice().compareTo(i2.getPrice()));

        cheapest = Collections.min(items,null);

        return cheapest;

}


}
```

Inside my main activity:

```
Store<Item> store = new Store<>();

for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            store.addItem(items.get(i).getA());
            store.addItem(items.get(i).getB());
}

System.out.println("Cheapest item price is " + store.cheapestItem().getPrice());
```

I get an error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:  com.java.school.B cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.Collections.min(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Collections.min(Unknown Source)
at com.java.school.Store.cheapestItem(Store.java:20)
at com.java.school.Main.main(Main.java:313)
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, since Eclipse is not pointing it out before runtime. Can somebody point me in the right direction? Is there another way to go about doing this?

Comment: You're sorting the list, although it's useless, but with a correct comparator. Then you call min(), which you must do, but with null as the comparator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to use your comparator in the `min` method, instead of null. This should allow it to get the result you need - a comparator cannot get the minimum if it doesn't know how to compare the items! You can remove the call to sort and add the comparator to the call to `min`. It would look like this:

```
public T cheapestItem(){
    return Collections.min(items, (i1, i2) -> i1.getPrice().compareTo(i2.getPrice()));
}
```

If this returns the most expensive instead of the cheapest, just change the order of your comparison from `t1.compareTo(t2)` to `t2.compareTo(t1)`.

Comment: That's technically correct. But a much better solution would be to keep using min(), with a correct comparator (which is used in the useless sort()), and to remove the sort. Finding the minimum is faster than sorting the whole list, and Collections.min() more clearly expresses the intent.

Comment: @JBNizet You're right that would be slightly more efficient - I edited my answer.

Comment: The last part is unnecessary. This will find the cheapest. The comparator could be reduced to `Comparator.comparing(Item::getPrice).

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a local variable which stores the cheapest item found and iterate through the list.

```
public T cheapestItem() {
    T cheapest = items.get(0);
    for (T item : items) {
        if (item.getPrice() < cheapest.getPrice()) {
            cheapest = item;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your exception shows that `T` must implement `Comparable` in order to use the method `Collections.min`.  You "prove" that to the compiler (and ensure it's true) in your not-shown definition of `Item`.  Declare that `Item implements Comparable` and ensure that there is a `compareTo` method there.